# how to determine if an image is symmetrical?-MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a 3D color image. I wish to plot its principal axis and its centroid. To do that, I have extracted each of the color channels, found the centroid and then proceeded to find the covariance matrix and eigenvalue. I am unsure as to whether this will help me plot the principal axis.

**My primary goal is to plot the principal axis so that I can find whether the image is symmetrical about that axis.**

This is the algorithm I would like to implement.

> Plot the principal axis of the image. The image is then rotated
>   (clockwise) to align its coordinate ( and ) axes with principal
>   inertia axis of the image. The image is then hypothetically folded
>   around the -axis and the the sum of the absolute grey-level
>   difference between the corresponding pixels( ) between the
>   overlapping folds was taken as the amount of asymmetry on the -axis.
>   The same procedure was performed for the -axis. Two asymmetry
>   measures were calculated from   and   as follows:

A1 = min (

, 

)

× 100%

A2 =
(

+ 

)

× 100%.

> The two asymmetry measures noted above ( 1 and  2) are computed
>   for each image channel, in the RGB colour space, resulting in the
>   total of six-coefficient (6D) colour asymmetry feature.

How do I plot the principal axis? I tried using **regionprops** function in MATLAB to plot the major axis, minor axis, centroid and orientation but I am unsure if this is the right approach. Should I use **PCA**?

Can I overlap the image using the **fliplr** function?

What do they mean same procedure for y-axis? If an image is asymmetrical over one axis then doesn't it mean its asymmetrical over the y-axis too?

I am unable to implement this algorithm. Please guide on how to code this in MATLAB.

https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/266988-how-to-flip-a-segmented-image-along-the-major-axis#answer_208875

This is a partial answer to my query but I am stuck at the initial part. How do I find the major axis and align in with the axes using imtranslate()?